# CreateJS - Change color in object

Tags: stage, createjs

I have a .fla file where I have symbols to change skin, hair and shirt colors in a boy draw. When I export it with CreateJS I got this:

```
// 1Hair
this.shape_226 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_226.graphics.f("#FCDEC4").s().p("AA").cp();
this.shape_226.setTransform(0.1,-95.3);`
```

There you can see a color (#FCDEC4) that stands for hair color, I tried replacing the color for one variable (boyHair), like this

```
// 1Hair
this.shape_226 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_226.graphics.f(boyHair).s().p("AA").cp();
this.shape_226.setTransform(0.1,-95.3);`
```

This is the init function of the file generated

```
//Modified from exported file of Flash Toolkit for CreateJS
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
    canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot=new lib.characters();

    stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage);
}
```

I set the value on my main JavaScript file like this:

```
var boyHair="#000000";
```

And works the first time (I guess at initialization stage) but if I modify the value later on the code, it has no effect on canvas draw, I tried with `stage.update()` but it does nothing as well.

Do you know if there's a way to change those colors dinamically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way - you will have to reconstruct your Shapes when the color changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this

```
 var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() 
{
canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
exportRoot=new lib.characters();
stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener ("tick", tick);
}
 tick =function()
 {
     var boyHair="#000000";
     stage.update();
 }
```